# Etimología de "de calle"

Tags: etimología

Me gustaría saber de dónde proviene la expresión `de calle`. Su uso, a mi juicio, indica facilidad/seguridad en la consecución de algo:

> El partido de mañana lo ganará el Barça **de calle**.
>
> ¿Qué prefieres, una bicicleta o un Ferrari? El Ferrari **de calle**.

¿De dónde proviene? ¿Alguna propuesta de una definición más exacta? ¿Algún otro uso?

Comment: https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/traerllevar-de-calle-486/

Comment: Hola @ukemi, el significado lo sé, pero me gustaría saber de dónde viene. Saludos y gracias por la aportación :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Viene del dicho "llevar(se) de calle":

> [llevar, o llevarse, de calle](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6pegX8v#8SrYbgC)
>
> 1. locs. verbs. coloqs. Ganar con suma facilidad algo que está competido.
> 2. locs. verbs. coloqs. Vencer fácilmente en una confrontación dialéctica.
> 3. locs. verbs. coloqs. Conquistar a alguien, atraerlo, engatusarlo.

Es frase antigua. [Una de las primeras ocurrencias](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=62&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=040119%5C008%5CC003O04012019081809371.1012.1008&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20de%20calle%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto62) que he visto en el CORDE es de ~1654:

> Dícese quieren invadir aquellos Estados por tres partes el Francés, el Inglés y el Príncipe Francisco de Lorena, cada uno con 30.000 hombres, que si fuese así, se los llevarán de calle como bolos [...]

Pero en diccionarios no aparece hasta 1705 SOBRINO:

[image]

> Dirigir a alguien tocando el tambor, es decir, tener gran ventaja sobre él en el juego, o de otra forma.

En las guerras era y es costumbre, tras tomar una ciudad o ganar una guerra, que el vencedor hiciera una marcha triunfal por sus calles, en la cual se llevaba también a los prisioneros y vencidos (los que podían caminar, al menos). También se hacía con los condenados por ciertos delitos para mayor escarnio de su persona, etc.<sup><sub>1</sub></sup>

*"Llevarse a alguien de calle"* es una manera figurada de decir que se le ha vencido con tanta facilidad que se lo han llevado a dar ese "paseo de la derrota" por las calles, bajo el mando del vencedor.

Este dicho se sigue usando hoy en día tal cual, aplicado también a eventos (*"se ha llevado el partido de calle"*), pero es ya frecuente el uso de *"de calle"* como forma abreviada de transmitir el mismo concepto.

<sup><sub>1</sub></sup><sup><sub>Ejemplos de esto los hay a miles, tanto en la realidad como en la ficción, y bien recientes. Desde los desfiles pos Segunda Guerra Mundial con los vencidos alemanes desfilando por las calles de Moscú, hasta el paseo de la vergüenza de cierto personaje por las calles de Desembarco del Rey en Juego de Tronos.</sub></sup>

Comment: Qué curioso. Muchísimas gracias por tomarte la molestia de dar una respuesta tan elaborada. ¡Te la valido!